# Signing F# Assembly

Tags: .net, f#, strongname, assembly-signing

I'm having a lot of trouble trying to sign a F# class library project.
First I've tried this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17777014/signing-an-f-assembly-strong-name-component), using the *AssemblyKeyFileAttribute* but had no success.
I also tried to add the flag "--keyfile:keyfile.snk" to the project properties ("Other Flags" field in "Build" tab) and It did't worked too. I'm using Visual Studio 2013, and It does not shows the "Signing" tab like C# class library projects.

All the attempts results in the following error:

**FSC: error FS2014: A problem occurred writing the binary 'obj\Release\ExcelFinancialFunctions.dll': A call to StrongNameGetPublicKey failed (Value does not fall within the expected range.)**

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

FWIW, here's how I sign [ZeroToNine](https://github.com/ploeh/ZeroToNine): Instead of using Visual Studio, I do it as part of the build script. Essentially, it's done by using `AssemblyOriginatorKeyFile` and `SignAssembly`:

```
MSBuild.exe /property:AssemblyOriginatorKeyFile=mykey.snk /property:SignAssembly=true
```

You can see (almost) all the nitty-gritty details in the ZeroToNine repo, including [the actual build script I use for signing](https://github.com/ploeh/ZeroToNine/blob/master/build-release.sh). The only detail missing from the public repo is the actual .snk file, because it would make no sense to have a strong name key if it was publicly available.

Here's how I call the build script from Bash:

```
build-release.sh ../ZeroToNine.snk
```

As you can see, I have my .snk file residing outside of the repo, and pass it in as an argument to the script.

Comment: This is a nice solution indeed. I didn't know that msbuild has It's own signing mechanism, however I managed to solve the signing problem using ilmerge (assembly linker - al didnt worked too!) although that is not ilmerge purpose. Since this is a better solution than mine, I'll mark it as correct answer. Thanks!